# xslt change attribute in element

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm a beginner with xlst. I have this xslt code:

```xml
<xsl:for-each select="marc:datafield[@tag=100]">
  <origination>
    <persname encodinganalog="100" role="creator">
      <xsl:if test="marc:subfield[@code='a']">
        <xsl:value-of select="marc:subfield[@code='a']" /></xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="marc:subfield[@code='D']">,
        <xsl:value-of select="marc:subfield[@code='D']" /></xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="marc:subfield[@code='b']">,
        <xsl:value-of select="marc:subfield[@code='b']" /></xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="marc:subfield[@code='c']">,
        <xsl:value-of select="marc:subfield[@code='c']" /></xsl:if>
    </persname>
  </origination>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I want to update the attribute "@encodinganalog" of "persname" if the transformed source-xml has a certain subfield.
E.g. if the following expression is true:

```xml
<xsl:if test="marc:subfield[@code='a']"></xsl:if>
```

I want "encodinganalog" to be "100$a"

If all the following expressions are true:

```xml
<xsl:if test="marc:subfield[@code='a']">
  <xsl:value-of select="marc:subfield[@code='a']" /></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="marc:subfield[@code='D']">,
  <xsl:value-of select="marc:subfield[@code='D']" /></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="marc:subfield[@code='b']">,
  <xsl:value-of select="marc:subfield[@code='b']" /></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="marc:subfield[@code='c']">,
  <xsl:value-of select="marc:subfield[@code='c']" /></xsl:if>
```

The value of "encodinganalog" should be "100$a$D$b$c"

How is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `xsl:attribute` to add dynamic attributes to your output XML

```
<origination>
  <persname role="creator">
    <xsl:attribute name="encodinganalog">
      <xsl:text>100</xsl:text>
      <xsl:if test="marc:subfield[@code='a']">
        <xsl:text>$a</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="marc:subfield[@code='D']">
        <xsl:text>$D</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="marc:subfield[@code='b']">,
        <xsl:text>$b</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="marc:subfield[@code='c']">
        <xsl:text>$c</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </persname>
</origination>
```

Note you do have a bit of code-repetition here, so you could simplify it a bit using templates

```
<origination>
  <persname role="creator">
    <xsl:attribute name="encodinganalog">
      <xsl:text>100</xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="marc:subfield[@code='a']" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="marc:subfield[@code='D']" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="marc:subfield[@code='b']" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="marc:subfield[@code='c']" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </persname>
</origination>
```

And then have a template match like this

```
 <xsl:template match="marc:subfield">
     <xsl:text>$</xsl:text>
     <xsl:value-of select="@code" />          
 </xsl:template>
```